# substring comparison in perl

Tags: string, perl, loops, pattern-matching, match

Im working on comparing 2 substrings `sub1` and `sub2` from 2 initial strings `seq1` and `seq2` allowing only one mismatch `$k` is the length of subsequence

```
foreach (my $i = 0; $i < length($seq1) - $k; $i += 1) {
    my $sub1 = substr($seq1, $i, $k);
    foreach (my $j = 0; $j < length($seq2) - $k; $i++) {
        my $sub2 = substr($seq2, $j, $k);
        my $diff = $sub1 ^ $sub2;
        my $num_mismatch = $diff =~ tr/\0//c;
        if ($num_mismatch == 1) { 
            $d{$sub1}++;
        }
    }
}
foreach (keys %d) {
    print "$_\n";
}
```

**When I run the code It gets stuck until i kill the process and it doesnt give any result. Any Help about this ? **

Comment: Consider using perl-style for loops instead of c-style. E.g. `for my $j (0 .. (length($seq2) - 1 - $k))`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
foreach (my $j=0;$j<length($seq2)-$k;$i++)
```

should be

```
foreach (my $j=0;$j<length($seq2)-$k;$j++)
                                   # ^^
```

Comment: +1 Nice catch there. Although you might want to highlight the `j` there, as it was difficult to spot.